# Is it safe to use one instance of a Model to load several different entities?

Tags: best-practice

Are there side-effects, or issues with doing something like this:

```
// Retrieve the Model once
$model = Mage::getModel('some/model';

// Load several different instances
foreach($idlist as $id)
{
    $entity = $model->load($id);
}
```

Or should the Model be retrieved within the loop?

```
// Load several different instances
foreach($idlist as $id)
{
    // Retrieve the Model once per instance
    $model = Mage::getModel('some/model';
    $entity = $model->load($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are side effects to using the same model instance for loading more than one instance.
When calling `load` on a model, the data from the model is merged with the values from the database.
So in case the second instance has a field set to `null` in the database there is a chance that it won't be `null` if it had a different value in the previous instance.

Use the second approach if you have to. But using `load` in a loop is not recommended.

Here is what can happen if you use the same model instance for multiple load statements: [Product loop giving incorrect images](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10041/146)

Answer (score 0):

Any model load is *very* consuming. Your second solution is a tad better but still not great. Most of people use "load()" because it's the easiest way to get all the data from a model. Although the best solution is to actually add this data to the collection and only select what you need.

Comment: I assume you're referring to something like `Mage::getModel('some/model')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id' -> array('in', array(1,2,3))`?

We usually do it that way, this question was specific to one to many vs one to one getModel():load() calls--so a foreach better demonstrated it.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you shouldn't even load the model, it's going to be greedy regardless of the solution you go for.